# CMake: configuring CMake with multiple directories

Tags: cmake

**Background**

I'm trying to learn CMake, and I've been trying to learn how to build my system by having individual CMakeLists.txt files in each directory. One note is that main.cpp #includes `enemy.h`. A simplified version of my file structure looks like this structure looks like this:

```
mainfolder
|
|---- build
|        |---- CMake stuff
|---- enemy
|        |
|        |---- enemy.cpp
|        |---- enemy.h
|        |---- CMakeLists.txt
|
|---- fighter.h
|---- fighter.cpp
|---- main.cpp
|---- CMakeLists.txt
```

Here are my CMakeLists.txt files:

*mainfolder/CMakeLists.txt*

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.0)
project (game) 

add_subdirectory(enemy)  

set(HEADERS
    fighter.h
)

set(SOURCES
    main.cpp
    fighter.cpp
)

add_executable(${PROJECT_NAME} ${SOURCES} ${HEADERS})
target_link_libraries(${PROJECT_NAME} enemy)
```

*mainfolder/enemy/CMakeLists.txt*

```
add_library(enemy enemy.cpp enemy.h)
target_include_directories(enemy PUBLIC ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR})

target_link_libraries(enemy )
```

**Problem/What I've Tried**

I can't the system to build, and I am wildly bamboozled and lost. My current attempt as shown is based on this [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61355040/cmake-link-a-library-from-a-parent-directory), but I've also tried to simply have

```
target_include_directories(${PROJECT_NAME} PUBLIC enemy)

target_link_directories(${PROJECT_NAME} PRIVATE enemy)


target_link_libraries(${PROJECT_NAME} enemy)
```

In *mainfolder/CMakeLists.txt* and and `add_library(enemy enemy.h enemy.cpp)` in *mainfolder/enemy/CMakeLists.txt* and as shown at around 6:50 in [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=kEGQKzhciKc). With this configuration, `cmake ..` works, but I get an error that `enemy.h` doesn't exist in relation to main.cpp.

That error implies to me that the compiler still can't find `enemy.h`. I suppose I could just write `#include "enemy/enemy.h` in `main.cpp`, but that seems like it would defeat the purpose of CMake. Any suggestions on how to implement these multi-layered CMakeLists.txt files correctly?

Comment: `/enemy/CMakeLists.txt

add_library(computer` Why do you add a `computer` library from `enemy/CmakeLists.txt`?

Comment: Adapted the example from my current code and forgot to change that. Updated the post.

Comment: The config looks ok-ish. Remove `target_include_directories` and `target_link_directories`. Only `target_link_libraries`. Where have you put `target_link_libraries(${PROJECT_NAME} enemy)`? Did you re-run `cmake ..` after every modification? From what you are showing, I believe it should have worked. Please make sure that the files are 100% correct. Create [MCVE] - for example a repo with the code or such. ` the compiler still can't find enemy.h` Please post full error message from the compiler, please add the output of `make VERBOSE=1` or `cmake --build .. --verbose`.

Comment: Small clarification/addon to @KamilCuk s comment: The path you pass to `cmake --build` and cmake for reconfiguration or build should be the path to the directory where you already set up the project. I assume this is `.` or `build` depending rather than `..`.

Comment: @KamilCuk ok; I got it to work. And yeah; I copied my code over, but I was careless and didn't test the copied version after. Thank you for the help!

Comment: @KamilCuk one more question: are there any special accomodations that need to be made if a file deeper in the tree includes a file earlier on (ex. `enemy.h` `#include`s `fighter.h`)?

Comment: `if a file deeper in the tree includes a file earlier` That's spaghetti code, do not do that. Build your dependencies in a pyramid or a tree, not in spaghetti. If enemy.h depends on fighter.h and fighter depends on enemy, most probably they should be in the same module or in the same level. `any special accomodations` No idea - it's hard to say what qualifies as special. You just normally have to add proper include_directories to enemy, nothing special.

Answer (score 1):

I haven't tested it with cmake, printed from memory. The template is commonly used.

*mainfolder/CMakeLists.txt*

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.22)
project (game)
add_executable(game main.cpp fighter.cpp fighter.h)
add_subdirectory(enemy) # grab the library and headers (or path to headers)
target_link_libraries(game PRIVATE enemy) # link `game` to `enemy`
```

*mainfolder/enemy/CMakeLists.txt*

````
add_library(enemy STATIC)
target_sources(enemy PRIVATE enemy.cpp PUBLIC enemy.h) 
# If you library is being used somewhere else, 
# you can remove last 'PUBLIC' and uncomment next three lines
# target_include_directories(enemy PUBLIC
#  $<BUILD_INTERFACE:${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}>
#  $<INSTALL_INTERFACE:include/enemy>  # <prefix>/include/enemy )
```
````